# Do syllogisms apply to probabilistic statements?

Tags: probability, logic

I came across a statement that triggered my logic 101 alarm on another SE site, 
regarding risk factors for an illness. The statement was similar to this (modified):

> Favoring green jelly-beans is one of the risk factors for paralytic dispepsia, i.e. 
>   paralytic dispeptics are more likely to favor green Jelly-Beans.

I parsed this sentence as:

Favoring green jelly beans increases the probability that you'll suffer tummy aches.

*Therefore:*

If you have tummy aches, you are more likely someone who favors green jelly-beans.

I know That "A implies B" is not equivalent to the proposition "B implies A" (but rather,
equivalent to "Not(B) implies Not(A)") so I'd dismiss that example as a fallacy *if* there was not an element of probability involved. But given it *is* a probabilistic statement I'm unsure if this is valid inference or not.

Am I wrong in applying that syllogism in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not in a logical setting here, we are not talking about implication, we are talking about conditional probability. Let's take this example

```
p(i prefer green jelly beans) = 0.5
p(i have tummy aches | i pefer green jelly beans) = 1
p(i have tummy aches | i do not prefer green jelly beans) = 0.5
```

These conditional probabilities contain way more information than just 'i prefer green jelly beans' => 'i have tummy aches'. If i have tummy aches, then the likelihood of me prefering green jelly beans is `0.5*1 + 0.5*0.5 = 0.75`!

So yes, it is correct.

Comment: a previous revision mentioned Bayesian networks. Is your argument correct no matter what the structure of the model connecting those RV's is? if there are other, perhaps latent variables involved?

Comment: As long as the distribution is the same as in my example, and the other latent variables are not observed (only observation is my tummy ache), then yes. I was thinking of a direct connection between jelly beans and tummy aches, but it works in any network where those three equations are true, and only tummy aches are observed.

Comment: Right, since marginalization in any network consistent with those statements would imply the conclusion, and only obervation can change the results of marginalization. I guess with "other things being equal" thrown in, it works.